# How to escape quotes in while creating a textbox in jquery / javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a couple of span elements and I need to get the contents of these span elements into a textbox so the user can edit.

There might be any number of span elements, so the textboxes have to be created at runtime. The problem I'm having is that when the text contains a single quotes, it's messing with my text box values since it closes one of the quotes..

This is how I am creating my textbox:

```
var spanContent = $(value).text();
var tmpTextBox = "<input type='text' id='t" + index + "' value='" + spanContent  + "' class='dynTxt' />";
```

Notice the **value='" + spanContent  + "'** part, this is where it's breaking if `spanContent` has a single quote in it.. Now, I know I can do this:

```
value = \"" + spanContent + "\"
```

which works fine.. but, when the `spanContent` has double quotes, it breaks again..

What is the safest way to escape both single quotes and double quotes in this situation, please? I cannot html encode them because textbox values doesn't support them..

I have created a small reproduction of this [on jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/MTcbX/1/) for you to play with..

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For starters, if you're using jQuery take advantage of how modular it can be when creating elements. Not only is writing out the HTML elements bad from a security perspective, it's also prone to errors (as you've established). However, you'll be happy to know there is always a better way:

```
var input = $('<input />',{
  'type': 'text',
  'id': 't'+index,
  'value': spanContent,
  'class': 'dynTxt'
});
```

Now you have a new `<input>` element that can be attached, manipulated, etc. You can also do it the "long" way:

```
var input = $('<input />')
  .attr({'type':'text','id':'t'+index})
  .val(spanContent)
  .addClass('dynTxt');
```

Which results in the same element being generated:

```
<input type="text" id="t_index_" value="_spanContent_" class="dynTxt" />
```

The best part is that any problems (like quotes) will be solved for you, leaving you to just write the content you need.

Comment: You need to quote `class`, also jQuery is optimized for `"<input>"`. `'<input />'` works but it's extra work (and typing :P).

Comment: @Esailija: Indeed, good catch. FF can handle it, but IE doesn't like it. ;-)

Comment: Aah! It's not that I chose to create input elements that way, it's just that I didn't know any better.. that I could do it this way, thanks, will try it now!

Comment: I just found out that I could do this with jquery and was impressed.  Where can I find this in the documentation?

Comment: @blake305: [`.text(textString)`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) -- _We need to be aware that this method escapes the string provided as necessary so that it will render correctly in HTML._

Comment: Didn't know about this, it's a good way to declare new elements. Has this always been in jQuery, or introduced at a particular version?

Comment: @JDandChips: ["version added: 1.4"](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes) (blue box on docs page) ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
var tmpTextBox = $("<input>", {
    type: "text",
    id: "t" + index,
    val: spanContent,
    'class': "dynTxt"
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MTcbX/3/)**

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to concatenate the strings, how about setting the value after creating the element?

```
var spanContent = $(value).text();
var tmpTextBox = "<input type='text' id='t" + index + "' class='dynTxt' />";
$('#container').append($(tmpTextBox).val(spanContent));
```

Here is your updated jsFiddle showing this in action: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MTcbX/4/)

Looks like we all said pretty much the same thing. As mentioned in the other answers you can apply this same general idea to all of the attributes, not just value.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat heavy-handed option, if the text is only ever going to be used as marked-up text in a browser, is to replace all the single-quotes with its HTML ascii representation.  In this case:

```
var spanContent = $(value).text().replace("'", "&#39;");
```

has the desired effect.

Comment: hm, I was so sure this wouldn't work.. but it does, why does it work? How does textbox know to convert ``&#39;`` to ``single quote``, but not ``&quote;`` ? sorry if this is a stupid question!

Comment: Because &quote; isn't correct.  Double quotes are &quot; and single quotes don't have a name in the HTML ascii codes, hence using the ascii number.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tf = document.createElement("input");
tf.setAttribute("type","input");
tf.setAttribute("name","_tf");
var txt = "Hello. This using slash \\ quote \"";
tf.setAttribute("value",txt);
document.childNodes[1].appendChild(tf);
```

This is simply in pure javascript
working live [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ekuzez/edit#javascript,html)